# Grouping in arrayList of arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8

Hi I have a String ArrayList of ArrayList. A sample is shown below:

```
  [[765,servus, burdnare],
   [764,asinj, ferrantis],
   [764,asinj, ferrantis],
   [764,asinj, ferrantis],
   [762,asinj, ferrantis],
   [756,peciam terre, cisterne],
   [756,peciam terre, cortile],
   [756,peciam terre, domo],
   [756,asinj, ferrantis]]
```

Is it possible to get a list of unique values at index 1 for each value of index 0...The result I am expecting is:

```
765 - [servus]
764 - [asinj]
762 - [asinj]
756 - [peciam terre, asinj]
```

I was trying a series of if statements however did not work

Comment: did you try to write something already?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: This is the time, you should create a custom object instead of just using a `List<List<String>>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can group by index-0 element and collect index-1 elements in a `Set` to get unique

```
List<List<String>> listOfList = ...//

Map<String, Set<String>> collect = listOfList.stream()
        .filter(l -> l.size() >= 2)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(0), Collectors.mapping(l -> l.get(1), Collectors.toSet())));
```

Answer (score 1):

One of possibel variant. Just iterate over the given list and build `Map` with required `key` and `Set` as value to ignore duplicates.

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> group(List<List<String>> listOfList) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    listOfList.forEach(item -> map.compute(item.get(0), (id, names) -> {
        (names = Optional.ofNullable(names).orElseGet(HashSet::new)).add(item.get(1));
        return names;
    }));

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you have a `List<List<String>>` as the source, you can use `forEach` + `computeIfAbsent`:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(l -> map.computeIfAbsent(l.get(0), k -> new HashSet<>()).add(l.get(1)));
```